# State machine: validation before initial save in database?

Tags: validation, design-patterns, state-machine

This is a question regarding state machines in general, I don't need help with the actual implementation. Imagine a state machine that formalizes a simple bug report, from inception to its final demise. The bug might transition across states such as "NEW", "CONFIRMED", "RESOLVED", "REOPENED", and "CLOSED". Along with every state transition there is also some accompanying validation code, which could for instance make sure that when moving from NEW to CONFIRMED we have recorded who confirmed it.

My question is related to the initial state – when the bug is just "NEW". It's tempting to say that initial validation is not part of the state machine (e.g. making sure that the bug actually has some description, for instance, before saving it with state "NEW" in the database). But isn't that also a state transition, from "just created" to "NEW"? Shouldn't that transition be validated like any other transition? Isn't it artificial and sub-optimal to separate the initial validation from all other validations?

On the other hand, if we do create a "fake" initial state (say, "CREATED"), along with its respective transition ("CREATED" --> "NEW"), then what happens when that transition isn't validated? If it is validated, it's all good – we switch states and we save the object with the new state (actually called "NEW" here) in the database. But if it doesn't validate then we obviously don't want to save it in the database, and that breaks the state machine pattern by not having an initial state and a final state (we would have an initial state, albeit a fake one – "CREATED" –, but two final states – "CLOSED" and "DELETED"). Not only that, but the "DELETED" state would also be fake, in that there will never be any persistent objects with that state (just as there will never be any persistent objects with state "CREATED").

How do you handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after further investigation it looks like the pattern does solve my issue by itself: in some (most?) state machine models, there is in fact an [initial transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Basic_UML_state_diagrams) that **ends** in the **initial** state. So there is in fact a "fake" initial state, as far as the actual code is concerned, but that state must not be considered a real state in the state machine.

Comment: I would have answered the same. The initial state can also be seen as a label pointing to the first "real" state. It doesn't always have a transition. I don't think the rules are very strict, so you can use validation if you want.